# unrecognized selector sent to instance for button

Tags: ios, scrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I made a tab bar application like as a segmented controller using the HMSegmented Controller example. It was downloaded from Github and then I inserted my own xib view into this segment so I wrote a code for this.

```
ContactusViewController *contactus=[[ContactusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ContactusViewController" bundle:nil];
[contactus.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.scrollView insertSubview:contactus.view belowSubview:self.segmentedControl4];
```

Now I'm using a button on my ContactusViewController xib and when I click on it the application crashes. The error that returns is "unrecognised selector sent to instance".

Please give me solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check the mapping of the method with the button.
Second in your view controller add the contactus as `childViewController`.

```
[self addChildViewController:contactus];
```

Comment: but bro i want my contact view controller in to the scrollview. because i want all my view is scrollable.

Comment: yes that is ok, but just add the above line in your code apart from the code which you have written to add in the scrollview. by adding the childviewcontroller it will not throw "unrecognised selector sent to instance".

Comment: thnx #Ujjwal and @Anbu Karthik i got the solution your answer was right #Anbu Karthik thnx a lot

Comment: have a happy day bro,if its works give the vpvote and marks for the answer